# Import data to an excel online

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, openxml, powerquery, excel-online

What would be the best option to programmatically import large dataset (10 MB) file into an excel online workbook and protect the cells.

Dataset file CSV / Parquet format is stored in azure data lake storage.

I reviewed the Microsoft Graph API however I could not find a way to protect the range of cells. Only worksheet can be protected. Also could not find any API to import data.

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: How many rows is that? That file size seems way too big for Excel.

Comment: Around 200,000 rows with 15 columns